# How can I create a autorun.inf for executables in subdirectory, with parameters, on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, autorun

I'm trying to configure autorun.inf on a `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` tagged USB flashdrive to run an .exe file from a subdirectory with parameters. 
So far I have had no luck using the information provided by [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969327.aspx#AutoRun_Commands). I've also looked at several other questions here <sub>[1](https://superuser.com/questions/1182828/force-usb-autorun-on-windows-10) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/314063/how-to-autorun-a-html-file-from-usb-drive)</sub>, and made sure AutoRun is [enabled](https://www.howtogeek.com/236241/how-to-enable-disable-and-customize-autoplay-in-windows-10/) and disabled the group policy as explained in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/124393/721369).

One thing I noticed in the msdn [shell_verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969327.aspx#shell_verb) was the inconsistent usage of `/` and `\` throughout this manual—I tried both ways but either seemed to work *(I assume that it should be `\`)*. My autorun file is located in the root folder, some of the features seem to work, namely `label=` and `icon=`.

My autorun file looks like this now:

```
[AutoRun]
action=MyActionName
shellexecute= mysubfolder/myprogram.exe
shell/myverb/command=mysubfolder/myprogram.exe -myparameter
shell/myverb=Open &MyAction
open=mysubfolder/myprogram.exe -myparameter
icon=myprogram.ico
label=MyDeviceName
```

but neither autorun of the exefile, shell\verb or the open command works as expected. I've also tried to only use `open` alone with `action`, `label` and `icon`. I've also tried to use commands such as `run` or `start` in the `open`-option. I cannot find any documentation that explain if they need to be in a specific order either.

**Edit:** I've also tried to edit the registry key<sub>[3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/autorun-not-working/bf12dc06-bf90-4712-8886-0f77c3aaf099?auth=1)</sub> `NoDriveTypeAutoRun` in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` to decimal 145 *(hex 0x00000091)* but this did not work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Untested answer :

```
open=""mysubfolder\myprogram.exe -myparameter""
icon="mysubfolder\myprogram.exe,0"
action=MyActionName
```

The lines above should be enough - I don't think the others are needed.
Possibly the double-double-quotes can be replaced by single double-quotes.

Source : [Autorun.inf cannot deal with the sub-folders with space in their folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593311/autorun-inf-cannot-deal-with-the-sub-folders-with-space-in-their-folder-name)

Comment: Nice catch, however, it did nothing to fix my issue.

Comment: Does it work without the parameter?

Comment: No, it does not work with simple `open=app.exe` either. It's like the execution is disabled somehow.

Comment: It's maybe possible that Microsoft has decided to disable autorun for good. You should maybe do your tests on Windows 7, maybe in a VM. Once you know that your autorun.inf is correct and works on Windows 7 but not on Windows 10, then you will know that your problem is with Microsoft and not with the file.